# Please, help me to integrate this function.

Tags: calculus

I’m beginning to start my course calculus.
Now I'm doing this question.

$\int_{-2}^3{|x^2-1|}dx=\int_{-2}^{-1}{|x^2-1|}dx+\int_{-1}^1{|x^2-1|}dx+\int_{1}^3{|x^2-1|}dx$

Is this correct? Please someone give me a hint for this thanks.

Comment: That's right. Now the point of splitting like that (at the sign changes of the function inside the absolute value) was to be able to get rid of the absolute vales. How do you do that?

Comment: Remember,  if $u < 0,  | u | = -u $  Yes, it's counterintuitive to get -u as a result of absolute values, but -u  is really a doublenegative in hiding.  $-u = -  (\text{number less than zero})$

Comment: I got $\frac{24}{3}$ but is not correct.

Comment: @Sawaddee: so you should show us your calculations.

Comment: I got it. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int_{-2}^3{|x^2-1|}dx.
$$
$$
|x^{2}-1|=0,\implies{x=\pm1},\implies{{-1}\le{x}\lt{1}.}
$$
$$
\int_{-2}^3{|x^2-1|}dx=\left[\frac{x^{3}}{3}-{x}\right]_{-2}^{-1}+\left[-\frac{x^{3}}{3}+{x}\right]_{0}^{1}+\left[\frac{x^{3}}{3}-{x}\right]_{2}^{3}=\frac{22}{3}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
You can replace $|x^2-1|$ by $(x^2-1)$ if $(x^2-1)\ge0$ in an interval and by $-(x^2-1)$ if $(x^2-1)\le0$ in an interval:

So you continue:
$$\int_{-2}^3{|x^2-1|}dx\\=\int_{-2}^{-1}{|x^2-1|}dx+\int_{-1}^1{|x^2-1|}dx+\int_{1}^3{|x^2-1|}dx\\
\int_{-2}^{-1}{(x^2-1)}dx+\int_{-1}^1{-(x^2-1)}dx+\int_{1}^3{(x^2-1)}dx$$
All integrands are polynomials now.